How do you figure out how much total unique data you have stored in your Mac + iCloud?
How do you figure out how much total unique data you have stored in your Mac + iCloud?
My Mac seems to be getting low on storage.  Finder Info for my SSD shows "Available" jumping from low double digits of GB to 100s of GB depending on how much of iCloud Drive data gets purged.  When "Available" - "purgeable" gets low, suddenly "purgeable" drops a large amount and a bunch of iCloud Drive files suddenly get marked as being "in iCloud".  My interpretation of this is that my total unique data is around or more than the physical storage of my Mac.
This is why I would like to get a clear understanding of how much unique data I poses.  I think think of obvious ways of doing this such as turning off iCloud Drive on the Mac but I am looking for something less disruptive.
